# Three.js error with multiple canvases and JSON loaded geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to create multiple views and have copied the example code found [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_grid) exactly and it works perfectly.

However as soon as I replace the geometries with one that i've built in blender it throws an error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - three.js 21532
```

In the animate / render loop it renders the first canvases first frame, then the second canvases first frame it throws the error.

I know it has something to do with **object.__webglInit** being **undefined** for the second object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't share geometries across different renderers.

In your case, you will have to clone your geometry using a pattern like so:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry.clone(), material );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Aw so simple! I even came to that conclusion at one point but couldnt get it right haha. thanks!